# R count number of commas and string

Tags: r, nlp

I have a string:

```
    str1 <- "This is a string, that I've written 
        to ask about a question, or at least tried to."
```

How would I :

1) count the number of commas

2) count the occurences of '-ion'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `stringr` package has a function `str_count` that does this for you nicely.

```
library(stringr)

str_count(str1, ',')
[1] 2
str_count(str1, 'ion')
[1] 1
```

EDIT:

Cause I was curious:

```
vec <- paste(sample(letters, 1e6, replace=T), collapse=' ')

system.time(str_count(vec, 'a'))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.052   0.000   0.054 

system.time(length(gregexpr('a', vec, fixed=T)[[1]]))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.124   0.016   2.146 

system.time(length(gregexpr('a', vec, fixed=F)[[1]]))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.052   0.000   0.052
```

Comment: It's important to note that the time hit for `gregexpr()` is coming **entirely** from setting `fixed=T` (which is not needed here at all).  You might want to add the timings for `system.time(length(gregexpr('a', vec)[[1]]))`, which should be nearly identical to those for `str_count()`. This makes sense since `str_count()` is essentially a wrapper for `gregexpr()`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Good point. I was a little surprised how slow the `gregexpr` was.

Comment: Me too. That's why I checked. I really hadn't appreciated how much more slowly regular expressions are matched when `fixed=TRUE`. Good to know about that, so thanks for having adding those timings to your post!

Comment: In a `data.table` j-expression, you can do `dt[,n=str_count(str,'a')]` to get the number of `'a'` in `str` for each row, but `dt[,n= length(gregexpr('a',str)]` doesn't work, and the workaround (`Filter` & `unlist`) takes a very long time. Switching to `str_count` in my `data.table` j-expression decreased my execution time from several hours to 30 minutes with a large dataset.

Answer (score 6):

The general problem of mathcing text requires regular expressions.  In this case you just want to match specific characters, but the functions to call are the same.  You want `gregexpr`.

```
matched_commas <- gregexpr(",", str1, fixed = TRUE)
n_commas <- length(matched_commas[[1]])

matched_ion <- gregexpr("ion", str1, fixed = TRUE)
n_ion <- length(matched_ion[[1]])
```

If you want to only match "ion" at the end of words, then you do need regular expressions. `\b` represents a word boundary, and you need to escape the backslash.

```
gregexpr(
  "ion\\b", 
  "ionisation should only be matched at the end of the word", 
  perl = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works without having to install `stringr` library. However note that `length(gregexpr(",", "no commas", fixed = TRUE)[[1]])` and `length(gregexpr(",", "one , comma", fixed = TRUE)[[1]])` are both 1. So we need to check that `matched_commas[[1]][1]` is greater than 0.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_count(str1,fixed=',')
#[1] 2
stri_count(str1,fixed='ion')
#[1] 1
```

#### Benchmarks

```
vec <- paste(sample(letters, 1e6, replace=T), collapse=' ')
f1 <- function() str_count(vec, 'a')
f2 <- function() stri_count(vec, fixed='a')
f3 <- function() length(gregexpr('a', vec)[[1]])

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# f1() 18.41423 18.43579 18.37623 18.36428 18.46115 17.79397    20   b
# f2()  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000    20  a 
# f3() 18.35381 18.42019 18.30015 18.35580 18.20973 18.21109    20   b
```

Answer (score 3):

This really is an adaptation of Richie Cotton's answer.  I hate having to repeat the same function over and over.  This approach allows you to feed a vector of terms to match within the string:

```
str1 <- "This is a string, that I've written to ask about a question, 
    or at least tried to."
matches <- c(",", "ion") 
sapply(matches,  function(x) length(gregexpr(x, str1, fixed = TRUE)[[1]]))
#  , ion 
#  2   1
```

Comment: Again cause I was curious, you can also feed a vector of matches to `str_count`.  `str_count(str1, matches)` will return the same  2 and 1.