# Detecting a word in a string in R

Tags: r

I have the [BigQuery Dataset with Reddit Comments](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_01?pli=1). It has multiple columns, one which is the body column with the actual comment. I now want to search for a certain word, like a brand mention, for instance "BMW" in the body column and create a subset of the rows which contain "BMW" in data$body.

The dataset looks similar to this:

```
str(data)
data.frame: 75519 obs. of 113 variables
$ body: chr "...." .....
$ name: Factor w/ 22805 levels ....
....
```

I know the SQL command, which looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM dataset
WHERE body contains "BMW"
```

Is there a similar command in R?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: Solutions is

```
 bmw <- data[grep("BMW", data$body),]
```

Thanks to charleslmh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if characters in string in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128617/test-if-characters-in-string-in-r)

Comment: I just tried 

    grepl("BMW", data$body)

which gives me just Boolean expressions. I would like to have the rows, containing "BMW" in data$body in a subset. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Can i use these numerical positions of grep to make a subset out of the original dataframe? 

In the end i want to have a new dataset, where the body column contains "BMW", with all the other columns of the original dataset.

Comment: I guess `data[grep("BMW",data$body),]` could work.

Comment: Great, that worked! Thank you!!

Comment: If there's a solution, please post it as an answer. It's better for other users and the site in general.

Comment: `grep` gives a probably shorter vector of numerical positions of matches. `grepl` give a vector of TRUE and FALSE of the same length as its 2nd argument. `grepl is very useful when doing selections with `[` or `[[`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is

```
bmw <- data[grep("BMW", data$body),]
```

Thanks to charleslmh

Answer (score 1):

Either of these would succeed:

```
bmw <- data[ grep("BMW", data$body), ]  # numerical indexing
bmw <- data[ grepl("BMW", data$body), ] # logical indexing
```

The second one will succeed because the "[" function selects rows where logical vectors are TRUE in the "i" (the first) position.