# Search for a string in Data.Table in R

Tags: r

I am new to programming and doing some basic analysis in R Environment

I have two data tables 
1) DT1 with one column and 500 rows, containing list of countries
2) DT2 with 5 columns X 10000 rows, and in 1 column i have a text

Problem:
I want to search in DT2$Text column if any country name appears from DT1.
Can someone let me some piece of code for this such that the DT1 countries are searched in DT2$Text column for whole of DT2?

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Please provide [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also check this will help you solve your problem: [Test if characters in string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128617/test-if-characters-in-string-in-r)

Comment: Use `dput` to provide reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

```
DT1[,appear := lapply(.SD,function(x){any(grepl(x,DT2$Text))}),.SDcols = yourcolumninDT1]
```

should help you. 
If you want a proper answer you should give a reproducible example