# How to search for part of a string in R

Tags: r

Basically I'm tasked with making a simple phonebook in R.

I've made a large array which each entry following this pattern (FirstName LastName PhoneNumber, FirstName LastName PhoneNumber, etc.)

I need to do a simple print of someones info, like say first name was John it would return me all indexes starting with john.

I know I need an if statement but I do not know the proper syntax that I could just identify the beginning of the string. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- c('Mary Higgins', 'John Williams', 'Zhu Wang', 'Peter Johnson')
# all elements containing John
grep('John', x)
#[1] 2 4
# starting with John
grep('^John', x)
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Hi new to R, can you explain what grep is?

Comment: It is for searching patterns that match a "regular expression" in strings. The name comes from the unix tool: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep

Answer (score 0):

From this question: [Test if characters in string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128617/test-if-characters-in-string-in-r)

```
chars <- "test"
value <- "es"

grepl(value, chars)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an if statement, and I would try to avoid those in general (they're slow and sometimes convoluted to work with). You could try:

```
data <- data.frame(FirstName = c('Mary', 'John', 'Zhu', 'Peter'), 
                LastName = c('Higgins', 'Williams', 'Wang', 'Johnson'), 
                PhoneNumber = c("234-234-2342", "456-456-4564", "678-678-6788", "345-345-3455"))
data %>%
  filter(FirstName == "John")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression with `^` to specify that `John` is at the very beginning of the string. E.g.,

```
names <- c("John Hogg", "Hogg John")
grep("^John", names)

[1] 1
```

Alternatively, you could use `startswith`:

```
startsWith(names, "John")

[1]  TRUE FALSE
```