# What's the difference between the str_detect function in stringer and grepl and grep?

Tags: r, stringr, grepl

I'm starting to do a lot of string matching in my work and I'm curious as to what the differences between the three functions are, and in what situations someone would use one over the other.

Comment: Have you checked official documentation? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_detect

Comment: My understanding is that in terms of outcomes they are pretty similar. However, the `stringr` package really just provides consistent/user friendly functions which are wrappers of the `stringi` package.  My understanding is that these tend to be faster.

Comment: I would start by digging into `?str_detect`, `?grepl`, `?grep`, `?str_which`, `?match` / ``%in%``. And definitely check out the stringr package documentation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`stringr` is a "A consistent, simple and easy to use set of wrappers around the fantastic 'stringi' package" ([from package description](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html)). The main advantage of `stringi` is the incredible speed of the package compared to base `R` - which `stringr` inherits for the most part. The output of the functions is the same in base as in stringr.

I use `stringi` to generate some random text for demonstration:

```
library(stringr)
sample_small <- stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(100)
```

`grep` provides the position of a pattern in the character vector, just as it's equivalent `str_which` does:

```
grep("Lorem", sample_small)
#> [1]  1  9 14 32 45 50 65 93 94
str_which(sample_small, "Lorem")
#> [1]  1  9 14 32 45 50 65 93 94
```

`grepl`/`str_detect` on the other hand give you the information for each element of the vector, if it contains the string or not.

```
grepl("Lorem", sample_small)
#>   [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#>  [12] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#>  [34] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [45]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [56] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#>  [67] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [78] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [89] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [100] FALSE
str_detect(sample_small, "Lorem")
#>   [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#>  [12] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#>  [34] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [45]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [56] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#>  [67] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [78] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [89] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [100] FALSE
```

There are many scenarios where the different outcome could make a difference for you. I'm usually using `grepl` if I'm interested in adding a new column to a data.frame that contains information on whether a different column contains a pattern. `grepl` makes this easier as it has the same length as the input variable:

```
df <- data.frame(sample = sample_small,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$lorem <- grepl("Lorem", sample_small)
df$ipsum <- grepl("ipsum", sample_small)
```

This way, some more elaborate tests are possible:

```
which(df$lorem & df$ipsum)
#> [1]  1  5 15 53 71 75
```

Or directly as a `filter` rule:

```
df %>% 
  filter(str_detect("Lorem", sample_small) & str_detect("ipsum", sample_small))
```

Now in terms of why to use `stringr` over base, I think there are two arguments: different syntax makes it a little bit easier to use `stringr` with pipes

```
library(dplyr)
sample_small %>% 
  str_detect("Lorem")
```

compared to:

```
sample_small %>% 
  grepl("Lorem", .)
```

And `stringr` is roughly 5x faster than base (for the two functions we are looking at):

```
sample_big <- stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(100000)
bench::mark(
  base = grep("Lorem", sample_big),
  stringr = str_which(sample_big, "Lorem")
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 base          674ms    674ms      1.48     415KB        0
#> 2 stringr       141ms    142ms      6.99     806KB        0


bench::mark(
  base = grepl("Lorem", sample_big),
  stringr = str_detect(sample_big, "Lorem")
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 base          679ms    679ms      1.47     391KB        0
#> 2 stringr       146ms    148ms      6.76     391KB        0
```

The difference is even more striking when we look for exact matches (the default is to look for regular expressions)

```
bench::mark(
  base = grepl("Lorem", sample_big, fixed = TRUE),
  stringr = str_detect(sample_big, fixed("Lorem"))
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 base          336ms  338.1ms      2.96     391KB        0
#> 2 stringr      12.4ms   12.6ms     79.1      417KB        0
```

However, I think the base functions have a certain charm to them, which is why I often still use them when writing code quickly. The option `fixed = TRUE` is one example. Wrapping `fixed()` around the pattern feels just a little awkward to me. Other examples would be the option `value = TRUE` in `grep` (I let you figure that one out yourself) and finally `ignore.case = TRUE` which, again looks a little awkward in `stringr`:

```
str_which(sample_small, regex("Lorem", ignore_case = TRUE))
#>  [1]  1  5  6  8  9 11 12 14 15 17 22 27 30 32 34 35 42 48 51 53 58 64 69
#> [24] 74 76 80 83 86 89 91 92 94 97
```

However, the reason this is awkward for me is probably just because I used base `R` for a while before learning `stringr`.

Another point to consider is that with `stringi`, you have even more features overall. So if you are determined to get into string manipulation, you might start to learn that package right away - although there are admittedly less tutorials and it might be a bit tougher to figure some things out.

Comment: Thank you this was super helpful and gave me a lot to think and read about moving forward!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your benchmarks. For both str_detect and str_which, I see no significant difference between them and their base counterparts. Using `fixed()` is faster than `fixed = TRUE`; however setting `perl = TRUE` in base is much faster than any of the stringr versions. On Windows, R 4.0.3.

Comment: That's quite strange. I repeated the benchmarks just now and get pretty much the same results under R 4.0.3, `stringr` 1.4.0. Also tested it on rstudio.cloud in case my computer was doing something weird. I can confirm though that `perl = TRUE` changes the picture. I never really use it though. Maybe there is a hidden trade-off?

Comment: In the first part of your post including the first code block you write about the packages `stringi` and `stringr`, but the way it is written now sounds like you might have mixed the packages up.

Comment: I added a small clarification, but I don't know what you mean. stringr is built on top of stringi. Not the other way around...