# Error when typing a code in R studio. (filter error "name" not found)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am still learning R studio and I am working with a list of cars and my wanting is to filter them so I have only the manual ones. The column for gearbox is trans. I tried a few ways but I get error "trans" not found or that it works but i see nothing in the filtered table. here is what I have:

Try 1: I get error for no trans found

```r
filter(mpg,trans=="manual")
mpg_manual <-filter(mpg, trans="manual")

View(mpg_manual)
```

Try 2:Empty table

```r
library(tidyverse)
view(mpg)
filter(mpg, "trans"=="manual")
view(mpg)
mpg_brum <-filter(mpg, trans=="manual")
?mpg_brum
require(dplyr)
mpg_brum <-filter(mpg, trans=="manual")
view(mpg_brum)
```

I explained eveything

Answer (score 1):

The other answers demonstrate ways to look for patterns, they work.

Here's why your code did not work, however:

1. `filter(mpg, trans="manual")` attempts to "assign" `"manual"` to a local variable named `trans`, using the single `=`. In `dplyr::filter`, this is an error, and logically it doesn't really work here anyway. (There *are* some query-languages such as mongo that use syntax like this, but not R or `dplyr`.)
2. `"trans"=="manual"` is comparing two different string literals, having nothing to do with the contents of `mpg`. The conditional returns a length-1 `FALSE`, which does not return any rows from the frame. If you had selected two *matching* string literals, then the conditional would return a length-1 `TRUE` which would return all rows of the frame, invariant, and I'm assuming that is not what you want.

   ```r
   nrow(mpg)
   # [1] 234
   filter(mpg, "manual"=="manual")
   # # A tibble: 234 × 11
   #    manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
   #    <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
   #  1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact
   #  2 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
   #  3 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact
   #  4 audi         a4           2    2008     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact
   #  5 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact
   #  6 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
   #  7 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact
   #  8 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact
   #  9 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p     compact
   # 10 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact
   # # ℹ 224 more rows
   # # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
   ```
3. Restating what the other answers are leaning towards: look at the data and you will notice that *none* of the values of `trans` are a simple `"manual"`:

   ```r
   unique(mpg$trans)
   #  [1] "auto(l5)"   "manual(m5)" "manual(m6)" "auto(av)"   "auto(s6)"   "auto(l4)"   "auto(l3)"   "auto(l6)"   "auto(s5)"   "auto(s4)"
   ```

If you want to find all of the manual transmissions, use a pattern as suggested above (e.g., `grepl` or `stringr::str_detect`). Otherwise you can check for one or more specific patterns using either `==` with a known-to-exist pattern, or `%in%` for one or more:

```r
filter(mpg, trans == "manual(m5)")
# # A tibble: 58 × 11
#    manufacturer model               displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
#    <chr>        <chr>               <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
#  1 audi         a4                    1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
#  2 audi         a4                    2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
#  3 audi         a4 quattro            1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact
#  4 audi         a4 quattro            2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) 4        17    25 p     compact
#  5 dodge        dakota pickup 4wd     3.9  1999     6 manual(m5) 4        14    17 r     pickup 
#  6 dodge        dakota pickup 4wd     5.2  1999     8 manual(m5) 4        11    17 r     pickup 
#  7 dodge        ram 1500 pickup 4wd   5.2  1999     8 manual(m5) 4        11    16 r     pickup 
#  8 ford         explorer 4wd          4    1999     6 manual(m5) 4        15    19 r     suv    
#  9 ford         f150 pickup 4wd       4.2  1999     6 manual(m5) 4        14    17 r     pickup 
# 10 ford         f150 pickup 4wd       4.6  1999     8 manual(m5) 4        13    16 r     pickup 
# # ℹ 48 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
filter(mpg, trans %in% c("manual(m5)", "manual", "known_not_present", "manual(m6)"))
# # A tibble: 77 × 11
#    manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
#    <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
#  1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
#  2 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact
#  3 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
#  4 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact
#  5 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact
#  6 audi         a4 quattro   2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) 4        17    25 p     compact
#  7 audi         a4 quattro   3.1  2008     6 manual(m6) 4        15    25 p     compact
#  8 chevrolet    corvette     5.7  1999     8 manual(m6) r        16    26 p     2seater
#  9 chevrolet    corvette     6.2  2008     8 manual(m6) r        16    26 p     2seater
# 10 chevrolet    corvette     7    2008     8 manual(m6) r        15    24 p     2seater
# # ℹ 67 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

In the `%in%` example, you can see that I'm including two patterns I know don't exist, but it doesn't matter, the rows where `trans` does match something in the `c(..)` vector are all returned.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the trans column is never exactly "manual". It contains manual but has additional info.

What you can do is use str_detect to find "manual" within the text.

```
mpg_manual <- filter(mpg, str_detect(trans, "manual"))
```

alternative with pipes:

```
mpg_manual <- mpg %>% filter(str_detect(trans, "manual"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grepl as well to check strings in column, and ignore.case specify it is needed to be case sensitive or not

```
mpg %>% 
  filter(grepl("manual", trans, ignore.case = T))
```

And I would suggest to take a look for this post, it has been comprehensively explained about working with string values

[What's the difference between the str_detect function in stringer and grepl and grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412700/whats-the-difference-between-the-str-detect-function-in-stringer-and-grepl-and)