grepl vs str_detect - what is the difference?
I found this old post Finding rows containing a value (or values) in any column
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = sample(c('M017', 'M018', 'M019', 'M20', 'Other'), 20, replace = TRUE),
  col2 = sample(c('m017', 'm018', 'm019', 'm20', 'Other'), 20, replace = TRUE),
  col3 = sample(c('AM017', 'BM018', 'CM019', 'DM20', 'Other'), 20, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

I want to change this such that:

it selects all columns with rows LIKE 'M017', 'M018'
it does not select rows LIKE 'M019', 'M20'

Here is the exact match:
df_filtered <- df %>% 
  filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c('M017', 'M018'))) %>%
  filter_all(all_vars(!(. %in% c('M019', 'M20'))))

I often get confused how to do this ... I get confused between str_detect and grepl.
For example:
df_filtered <- df %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ grepl('M017|M018', ., ignore.case = TRUE))) %>%
  filter(!if_any(everything(), ~ grepl('M019|M20', ., ignore.case = TRUE)))

df_filtered <- df %>% 
  filter_all(any_vars(grepl('M017|M018', ., ignore.case = TRUE))) %>%
  filter_all(all_vars(!grepl('M019|M20', ., ignore.case = TRUE)))

df %>% 
       filter(if_any(everything(), ~ str_detect(., regex('M017|M018', ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>%
        filter(!if_any(everything(), ~ str_detect(., regex('M019|M20', ignore_case = TRUE))))

Is there a correct way to do this?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412700/whats-the-difference-between-the-str-detect-function-in-stringer-and-grepl-and.
Short answer, str_detect is probably a bit faster.

Do you really need to use regex?
Exact matching looks straightforward, and potentially much faster.
...if_any(everything(), ~ .x %in% c('M017', 'M0'8))...
