# loop in all files in a directory with r script

Tags: r, unix

I have a directory which contains different subfolders and other files. I need to access each subfolder, read the .tsv file and carry out the following rscript. How to loop this rscript and run it from the terminal?

```
for(i in my_files){
  s <- read.csv('abundance.tsv',sep = '\t')
  colnames(compare)[1] <- 'target_id'
  colnames(s)[1] <- 'target_id'
  s1 <- merge(compare, s, by = "target_id")
  output.filename <- gsub("(.*?)", "\\1.csv", i)
  write.table(s1, output.filename)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.dirs()` returns a list of the directories in the given path and `list.files()` a list of files in a given path, see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html) for the documentation.

`list.dirs()` can be recursive or not, so you can get only directory at the first level and then call `list.dirs()` again on each sub-directories (inside a loop) or directly get all the sub-directories.

With these two functions you can build your `my_files` array (since I do not know exactly your directory structure, I can't give an example).

If you have multiples files and want to open only some of them, you can check if the file name contains some sub-string you want (e.g. the file extension). The way to do it is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128617/test-if-characters-are-in-a-string).