# Partial Match word from sentence in R

Tags: r, regex

I am looking to partial match string using %in% operator in R when I run below I get FALSE

```
'I just want to partial match string' %in% 'partial'
 FALSE
```

Expected Output is TRUE in above case (because it is matched partially)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128617/test-if-characters-are-in-a-string

Comment: `grepl('partial', 'I just want to partial match string')`

Comment: Why do you want to use the %in% operator?  this is exactly what grepl is for

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this. I saw %in% in few tutorials. Not sure difference between those two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to match partially from a sentence you should try using `%like%` from data.table, check below

```
library(data.table)
'I just want to partial match string' %like% 'partial'
 TRUE
```

The output is TRUE

Answer (score 1):

```
`%in_str%` <- function(pattern,s){
  grepl(pattern, s)
}
```

Usage:

```
> 'a' %in_str% 'abc'
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `strsplit` the string so each word in it is its own element in a vector:

```
"partial" %in% unlist(strsplit('I just want to partial match string'," "))
[1] TRUE
```

`strsplit` takes a string and breaks it into a vector of shorter strings. In this case, it breaks on the space (that's the `" "` at the end), so that you get a vector of individual words. Unfortunately, `strstring` defaults to save its results as a list, which is why I wrapped it in an `unlist` - so we get a single vector.
Then we do the %in%, which works in the opposite direction from the one you used: you're trying to find out if string `partial` is `%in%` the sentence, not the other way around.

Of course, this is an annoying way of doing it, so it's probably better to go with a grep-based solution if you want to stay within base-R, or Priyanka's data.table solution above -- both of which will also be better at stuff like matching multiple-word strings.

Comment: I do not follow this, bit advanced for my current understanding, yup will stick with above solution for now. Thank you much though

Comment: Added an explanation in my reply. Really not advanced stuff.