# I am trying to filter the data in R by omitting any raw in budget column with a currency other than us dollars

Tags: rstudio

[image: horror.movie]

I tried this but it's not working.

```
horror_movies %>% dplyr::filter(grepl("$", budget))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `fixed=TRUE` as an argument to grepl. For example...

```
horror_movies[grepl('$', horror_movies$budget, fixed=TRUE),]
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40062319/6101713) for a detailed explanation.