# test if words are in a string (grepl, fuzzyjoin?)

Tags: r, grepl, fuzzyjoin

I need to do a match and join on two data frames if the string from two columns of one data frame are contained in the string of a column from a second data frame.

Example dataframe:

```r
First <- c("john", "jane", "jimmy", "jerry", "matt", "tom", "peter", "leah")
Last  <- c("smith", "doe", "mcgee", "bishop", "gibbs", "dinnozo", "lane", "palmer")
Name  <- c("mr john smith","", "timothy t mcgee", "dinnozo tom", "jane  l doe", "jimmy mcgee", "leah elizabeth arthur palmer and co", "jerry bishop the cat")
ID    <- c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6", "ID7", "ID8")

df1 <- data.frame(First, Last)
df2 <- data.frame(Name, ID)
```

So basically, I have `df1` which has fairly orderly names of people in first and last name; I have `df2`, which has names which may be organized as "First Name, Last Name", or "Last Name First Name" or "First Name MI Last Name" or something else entirely that also contains the name. I need the `ID` column from `df2`. So I want to run a code to see if `df1$First` **and** `df2$Last` is somewhere in the string of `df2$Name`, and if it is have it pull and join `df2$ID` to `df1`.

My R guru told me to use `fuzzy_left_join` from the `fuzzyjoin` package:

```r
fzjoin <- fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("First" = "Name"), match_fun = "contains")
```

but it gives me an error where the argument is not logical; and I can't figure out how to rewrite it to do what I want; the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/fuzzyjoin/man/fuzzy_join.html) says that `match_fun` should be `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but I don't know what to do with that. Also, it only matches on `df1$First` rather than `df1$First` and `df1$Last`. I think I might be able to use the [grepl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128617/test-if-characters-are-in-a-string), but not sure how based on examples I've seen. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says that `match_fun` should be a *"Vectorized function given two columns, returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` as to whether they are a match."* It's not TRUE or FALSE, it's a function that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If we switch your order, we can use `stringr::str_detect`, which does return `TRUE` or `FALSE` as required.

```
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(
  df2, df1,
  by = c("Name" = "First", "Name" = "Last"),
  match_fun = stringr::str_detect
)
#                                  Name  ID First    Last
# 1                       mr john smith ID1  john   smith
# 2                                     ID2  <NA>    <NA>
# 3                     timothy t mcgee ID3  <NA>    <NA>
# 4                         dinnozo tom ID4   tom dinnozo
# 5                         jane  l doe ID5  jane     doe
# 6                         jimmy mcgee ID6 jimmy   mcgee
# 7 leah elizabeth arthur palmer and co ID7  leah  palmer
# 8                jerry bishop the cat ID8 jerry  bishop
```

Comment: I think you meant `by = c("Name" = "First", "Name" = "Last")` ;)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help! I'm getting this warning: Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX, context=`CHURCH???`)
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50); any advice?

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like some of your patterns might have regex special characters. Instead of `stringr::str_detect`, try `stringi::stri_detect_fixed`. A "fixed" pattern treats special characters (like question marks) as literals.